# detect if long long is present at compile time

Tags: c++, g++

boost.config checks stuff after including `<limits.h>` - if `ULLONG_MAX` or `ULONG_LONG_MAX` or `ULONGLONG_MAX` are defined (it also does per-compiler checks like if `_MSC_VER >= 1400`).

But if I pass `-std=c++98 -pedantic-errors` to gcc I cannot really use `long long` even if those things are defined. I can check for `__cplusplus` if it is equal or greater to `201103` but this does not correlate with the compiler flags - I can have it equal to 1997 and still be able to use `long long` - depending on what flags I've given.

So is there a way to truly detect if I can use `long long`?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one you're asking; the problem whose solution you believe is to "detect if I can use long long".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm writing a library and want to supply an overload of a function for ```long long``` if possible. The idea is to have as much basic types handled as possible.

Comment: I am imagining a function template that take any integer type, maybe with some SFINAE trick.

Comment: Use types defined in <cstdint>, int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, and int64_t.

Comment: @NickyC I already have a template that does default stuff and am trying to make as much specializations as possible. Also I'm using format specifiers in the specializations (or overloads) like ```%lld``` which are different for every type. I cannot use streams or other fancy stl headers because I need to rely only on ```cstdio```

Comment: Use your own condition like `#ifdef MYLIB_USE_LONG_LONG` and let the end user sort it out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that header is since c++11 and again I would be left making (what) checks before including it

Comment: You can use the stdint.h alias.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is C99 included in C++98? if yes - then I truly can use that header and it would work for me - or maybe I am being too pedantic and shouldn't focus on such small issues

Comment: "But if I pass ```-std=c++98 -pedantic-errors``` to gcc I cannot really use ```long long``` even if those things are defined." You can. See `__extension__`.

Comment: All compilers worth using these days will have stdint.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the preprocessor checks in boost I ended up suppressing the warning and thus `-pedantic-errors` did not complain:

```
#include <climits>
#if defined(_MSC_EXTENSIONS) || (defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1400))
#define MY_LIBRARY_HAS_DETECTED_LONG_LONG
#elif (defined(ULLONG_MAX) || defined(ULONG_LONG_MAX) || defined(ULONGLONG_MAX))
#define MY_LIBRARY_HAS_DETECTED_LONG_LONG
#endif

#ifdef MY_LIBRARY_HAS_DETECTED_LONG_LONG
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wlong-long"
#endif
// my overloads using long long
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif
#endif // MY_LIBRARY_HAS_DETECTED_LONG_LONG
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go along the lines of checking `__cplusplus > 201103`, and just tell people that they need to use `std=c++11` or it's equivalent if they want to use your library with `long long`. That's the straight forward and easy method.